# Issue with SwiftyJSON when parsing JSON with unicode characters

Tags: json, swift, unicode, spree, swifty-json

Here is the response I get from the API

```
2015-08-31 7:29:45 [GDMNetManagerSMB.swift-228]: response:     Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fd6c507c6a0> { URL: ... } { status code:     200, headers {
    Age = 0;
    "Cache-Control" = "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Tue, 01 Sep 2015 02:29:43 GMT";
    Etag = "\"b227c2...28c2034ac\"";
    Server = "ATS/5.2.1";
    Status = "200 OK";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    "X-Content-Type-Options" = nosniff;
    "X-Frame-Options" = SAMEORIGIN;
    "X-Request-Id" = "17f03082-2f44-436a-84f5-7f038e77988f";
    "X-Runtime" = "0.151788";
    "X-UA-Compatible" = "chrome=1";
    "X-XSS-Protection" = "1; mode=block";
} })
```

Then, in the code I print the json, and then try to extract "count" and "total_count"

```
NSLog("sjson :  \(sjson)")

let cnt = sjson["count"]
NSLog("count :  \(cnt)")

let tot_cnt = sjson["total_count"]
NSLog("total_count :  \(tot_cnt)")
```

Here is the console ouput

```
2015-08-31 19:46:57.416 MyApp[79763:2558418] sjson :      {"count":2,"total_count":2,"current_page":1,"per_page":25,"pages":1,"taxons":[{"taxons":[{"taxons":[{"taxons":[],"id":7,"name":"Burlesque","pretty_name":"Categories -\u003E Modern designs -\u003E Wacko -\u003E Burlesque","permalink":"burlesque","parent_id":5,"taxonomy_id":1,"updated_at":"2015-03-02T22:12:06.000Z"}],"id":5,"name":"Wacko","pretty_name":"Categories -\u003E Modern designs -\u003E Wacko","permalink":"wacko","parent_id":4,"taxonomy_id":1,"updated_at":"20    15-08-22T15:34:07.000Z"}],"id":4,"name":"Modern    designs","pretty_name":"Categories -\u003E Modern designs","permalink":"modern-designs","parent_id":1,"taxonomy_id":1,"updated_at":"2015-08-22T16:03:31.000Z"},{"taxons":[{"taxons":[],"id":6,"name":"Victorian","pretty_name":"Categories -\u003E Classic designs -\u003E Victorian","permalink":"victorian","parent_id":3,"taxonomy_id":1,"updated_at":"2015-06-11T20:07:52.000Z"}],"id":3,"name":"Classic designs","pretty_name":"Categories -\u003E Classic designs","permalink":"classic-designs","parent_id":1,"taxonomy_id":1,"updated_at":"2015-08-22T15:30:18.000Z"}]}
2015-08-31 19:46:57.417 MyApp[79763:2558418] count :  null
2015-08-31 19:46:57.417 MyApp[79763:2558418] total_count :  null
```

The only thing different from the usual scenario, is that the JSON contains unicode characters e.g.

```
"pretty_name":"Categories -\u003E Modern designs -\u003E Wacko -\u003E Burlesque"
```

I checked the following:

- the response is UTF-8 encoded

  ```
  "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
  ```
- the json is valid (used jsonlint.com - it is in fact the Spree endpoint /api/taxonomies/1/taxons)

  ```
    {
  "count": 2,
  "total_count": 2,
  "current_page": 1,
  "per_page": 25,
  "pages": 1,
  "taxons": [
      {
          "taxons": [
              {
                  "taxons": [
                      {
                          "taxons": [],
                          "id": 7,
                          "name": "Burlesque",
                          "pretty_name": "Categories -> Modern designs -> Wacko -> Burlesque",
                          "permalink": "burlesque",
                          "parent_id": 5,
                          "taxonomy_id": 1,
                          "updated_at": "2015-03-02T22:12:06.000Z"
                      }
                  ],
                  "id": 5,
                  "name": "Wacko",
                  "pretty_name": "Categories -> Modern designs -> Wacko",
                  "permalink": "wacko",
                  "parent_id": 4,
                  "taxonomy_id": 1,
                  "updated_at": "2015-08-22T15:34:07.000Z"
              }
          ],
          "id": 4,
          "name": "Modern designs",
          "pretty_name": "Categories -> Modern designs",
          "permalink": "modern-designs",
          "parent_id": 1,
          "taxonomy_id": 1,
          "updated_at": "2015-08-22T16:03:31.000Z"
      },
      {
          "taxons": [
              {
                  "taxons": [],
                  "id": 6,
                  "name": "Victorian",
                  "pretty_name": "Categories -> Classic designs -> Victorian",
                  "permalink": "victorian",
                  "parent_id": 3,
                  "taxonomy_id": 1,
                  "updated_at": "2015-06-11T20:07:52.000Z"
              }
          ],
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Classic designs",
          "pretty_name": "Categories -> Classic designs",
          "permalink": "classic-designs",
          "parent_id": 1,
          "taxonomy_id": 1,
          "updated_at": "2015-08-22T15:30:18.000Z"
      }
  ]
  }
  ```

What might be the issue here ?

UPDATE: I tried printing the SwiftyJSON error, here is what I get:

```
let cnt = sjson["count"].error
NSLog("count :  \(cnt)")
let tot_cnt = sjson["total_count"].error
NSLog("total_count :  \(tot_cnt)")


2015-09-01 09:24:30.543 SMBAppEnt[84325:2642079] count :  Optional(Error Domain=SwiftyJSONErrorDomain Code=901 "Dictionary["count"] failure, It is not an dictionary" UserInfo=0x7fca2f81f100 {NSLocalizedDescription=Dictionary["count"] failure, It is not an dictionary})
2015-09-01 09:24:30.543 SMBAppEnt[84325:2642079] total_count :  Optional(Error Domain=SwiftyJSONErrorDomain Code=901 "Dictionary["total_count"] failure, It is not an dictionary" UserInfo=0x7fca2cd45d90 {NSLocalizedDescription=Dictionary["total_count"] failure, It is not an dictionary})
```

Comment: FWIW, if I use the JSON from your question + your code it works in a sample app ([screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s89/sh/f63649bb-b54c-43ca-8765-09b237ce1f00/f7772a910f8c5b1c/res/fe2a3f35-60b3-4986-9036-f2a56413a762/skitch.png)).

Comment: Thanks Eric D. So it looks like when using NSURL directly, it works, good to know (I'm using Alamofire to pull the data). So I have a direction to investigate now !

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog("sjson :  \(sjson)")

let cnt = sjson["count"].string
NSLog("count :  \(cnt)")

let tot_cnt = sjson["total_count"].string
NSLog("total_count :  \(tot_cnt)")
```

OR

```
NSLog("sjson :  \(sjson)")

let cnt = sjson["count"]!.string!
NSLog("count :  \(cnt)")

let tot_cnt = sjson["total_count"]!.string!
NSLog("total_count :  \(tot_cnt)")
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not it. sjson["count"].int just prints nil